# Passing the windows authentication user data from client to a server in a ASP.NET MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have a database on a SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. The requirement is to offer windows authentication to the SQL server.

If I start the application out of the Visual Studio, then everything works fine. The application grabs the authentication data from the local system and connects to the database.

Of course the user of my local system is a valid database user.

The problem is if I try to use windows authentication while running the application on a remote server. Then it doesn’t take the user data of my local system. It seems to take the user data of the server or of the IIS. “IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0”

The connection string of a windows authentication connection contains no username/password, so I cannot just let the user type them in (But it would be also an acceptable solution), so I have to pass somehow the windows user data of the client, where the application is called, to the server where the application runs.

Does someone maybe know how to do it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: When using Windows authentication without impersonation, the identity of your application pool will be used: in your case this is a virtual account "ISS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0".  You can change this by using an Application Pool that is configured to use a different identity.  Or, if SQL Server is running on the same server as IIS, you can add the virtual account "ISS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0" as an SQL Server login.

Comment: The application does *not* grab any authenticated data at all. Either NTLM or Kerberos are used to verify the credentials against a principal (ie the Domain Controller) trusted by both. If the remote server is in a different domain, the credentials are invalid unless there is trust between the two domains. You need to enable impersonation *and* ensure the two machines are in the same or trusted domains, or you need to find a different authentication mechanism.